# Proposal: rename [jsx] to [altjs-jsx]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There seem to be two meanings for the acronym JSX. AltJS JSX and React JSX. As of now the latter seems to be the most popular, and many React-related questions are being erroneously tagged with the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag, instead of the proper [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) tag.

I propose to rename the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag to [altjs-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altjs-jsx) (feel free to propose a better name) to remove this ambiguity.

As of now I see 146 questions tagged with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx). Those could be retagged in a matter of days, and order would be restored.

**Update:** 
The situation is further worsened by the fact that [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) is a synonym of [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) as seen on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/synonyms

If you've added a [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag to the question and then trying to add [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) tag, your attempt is being silently ignored. No warning, you just don't see your tag added to the question. You have to somehow *know* that the tags are synonyms.

I imagine a lot of users will add a [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag instead.

Comment: What examples of an AltJS question do you have that is inappropriately or unreasonably tagged?

Comment: I have 146 examples of ReactJS questions that are unreasonably tagged.

Comment: I see tons of your retag suggestions in the edit review queue. I don't know about the etiquette of retagging, but it feels rather unilateral to just go ahead and do 100s of edits without waiting for community feedback.

Comment: Feedback on what exactly? As of now the tag jsx has a definition, and it's not related to React. It IS the wrong tag to use. The correct tag does exist. I'm suggesting here to give a new name to the jsx tag, so that people don't misuse it.

Comment: As I said, I don't know how this is dealt with usually - but coordinating with higher rep users who don't send every tag edit to the review queue would have been one thing. Also, I understand tag only edits are discouraged if they gloss over other, more substantial improvements that could be made to a post, and you edit exclusively tags and syntax highlighting.

Comment: That's true, I'd better stop that for now. In any case, I did retag a whole bunch already, but it won't prevent people from using the wrong tag in the future.

Comment: FWIW, there are now ~500 questions that are incorrectly tagged with `jsx` and `react-jsx`. This is a problem that should be addressed one way or the other.

Comment: I see no progress on this one way or the other. This is a real problem and the fact that the tag description does say that the [jsx] tag is regarding altjs-jsx does not stop people from mistagging their questions. There are now over 2000 jsx questions and the overwhelming majority seem to be concerning reactjs jsx and not altjs jsx.

Comment: There are also some questions about extendscript (the Adobe javascript ) that are also tagged [jsx], since that's the file extension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extendscript+jsx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx+adobe

Comment: @apokryfos As I understand the progress will happen if enough people vote on this ^^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, don't do this.

The "AltJS JSX" mentioned in the excerpt has - as far as I can tell after lengthy attempts to prove otherwise - never had even a single question asked about it. Rather, 100% of all questions in this tag are using it contrary to the excerpt and usage guidance. Rather than renaming the tag, we should therefore *repurpose* it by changing its description and excerpt to refer to React / Vue JSX, as I propose over at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386411/1709587.

(Also, by the way, [altjs-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altjs-jsx) would be a super-confusing name for the concept that the current excerpt refers to, since it's unrelated to Alt.js and the sense in which the current tag description uses the term AltJS is a fairly obscure one.)