# Should the jsx tag stop being a synonym to reactjs?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I realise that most people are asking about [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) when asking about JSX but JSX itself is not a strictly a reactJS topic. In fact Vue.js also allows using JSX and there is a babel jsx plugin for compiling Vue JSX. The ambiguity is apparent in the question [Vue v-on:click.native in JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198226/vue-v-onclick-native-in-jsx)

So question is should jsx stop being a synonym to reactjs?

Comment: I think the answer is a clear **yes**.

Comment: There used to be an burninate request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349578/should-we-burninate-jsx and slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315831/proposal-rename-jsx-to-altjs-jsx

Comment: There is a [tag:react-jsx] tag that's **also** a synonym of [tag:reactjs] so clearly [tag:jsx] doesn't need to be.

Comment: @rene I have no real strong feelings about keeping or deleting the tag. In an ideal world we'd keep it and people would only use it if they had JSX (but not react specific) questions. However I do understand this is not an ideal world so perhaps there is some merit in completely removing it and using a different tag for pure jsx questions or having a tag for each supported library (like in this case creating vue-jsx)

Comment: I have no opinion on it, nor feelings. I just happened to recall I saw that tag mentioned in the burnination worksheet that was created a couple of months ago which is why I linked to those posts.

Comment: Now I know why @apokryfos asked me if I want to use both react and vue! I didn't add `reactjs` tag...

Comment: Absolutely. JSX is used by multiple frameworks, not just React.

Comment: JSX is an XML syntax that is an extension of JavaScript. It is completely separate from React.

Comment: I am surprised to know that those tags are synonyms. Not only is jsx not mandatory in react, it can also be used in other front-end frameworks.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Due to popular demand, and a clear majority of 43 votes for and 1 vote against, I deleted the synonym. [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) are now separate. It is now the time to look at the other two pressing matters:

- [Should we burninate [jsx]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349578/should-we-burninate-jsx)
- [Proposal: rename [jsx] to [altjs-jsx]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315831/proposal-rename-jsx-to-altjs-jsx)