# De-synonymize the [react-jsx] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please revoke the [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?search=jsx) to [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs). Questions about the specific syntax and its transpilation should be tagged separately, they should not be tagged only for the generic framework. The JSX syntax is not even limited to ReactJS, it can be used with other frameworks as well.

We already [removed the synonymisation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370595/1048572) of [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) to [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), and we should do the same to [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx). In a further step, we should rename [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) to [jsx-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx-syntax), and [rename](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315831/1048572) [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) to [jsx-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx-lang) to fully disambiguate the JS syntax extension from the programming language. [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) probably should even be blacklisted afterwards.

Comment: related questions on [disambiguation of tsx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380384/wrong-usage-of-the-tsx-tag), and [burnination of jsx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349578/should-we-burninate-jsx).

Comment: Even speaking as someone who's worked a little with React in the past, the rationale here is hard to understand. Some extra exposition would make this easier for non-experts to follow, if you wanted to. (How many different JSX dialects are there? How do they differ? Is "React JSX" a distinct dialect that differs from some other flavour of JSX? Why does it make sense to assume that people who used the seemingly React-specific `react-jsx` tag are asking generic JSX questions while people who used the seemingly generic `jsx` tag are asking specifically about Alt.js?)

Comment: @MarkAmery They're not different dialects, they're completely unrelated but unfortunately go by the same name. (TBH I don't even have a clear idea what alt-jsx is or whether it has anything to do with JavaScript - the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315831/1048572) should make that case). This request here is primarily about removing the tag synonym between [tag:react-jsx] and [tag:reactjs].

Comment: @Bergi Oh. I see - following the links in the current `jsx` tag wiki, I see it was [last updated in 2015](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/) and is - as you say - unrelated to React's JSX. It doesn't use XML and the "X" does not stand for XML like in React's JSX. However, importantly, it also seems to have *nothing at all* to do with Alt.js; the tag Wiki reference to "AltJS" seems to be used in the sense of "JSX is an alternative JavaScript" rather than "JSX is built on top of Alt.js". The official docs never use the word "altjs" anywhere. So renaming to `altjs-jsx` would be confusing and wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, from Googling, it looks like "altJS" (as opposed to Alt.js) was once, many years ago, an obscure term of art for a language that compiles down to JavaScript? Meaning that e.g. TypeScript, CoffeeScript, React JSX, and https://github.com/jsx/JSX/ are all examples of altJSes? I guess per that usage, `altjs-jsx` technically makes sense... but what proportion of people asking questions about any of those tools have ever encountered the term altJS used in that way? Personally, I've never seen it in my entire career, and wrongly assumed here that `altjs` referred to the Alt.js library.

Comment: @MarkAmery Thanks for the investigation. Can you write that as an answer to the renaming proposal? (I guess [[tag:jsx-lang]] would be a proper alternative)

Comment: @Bergi Will write up this evening after work if nobody else has done so by then.

Comment: @MarkAmery and Bergi, if you have time, do take a look at the tsx one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380384/wrong-usage-of-the-tsx-tag as well. That's a smaller one, and can probably done before we get dirty with this.

Comment: @BhargavRao I think we should avoid [[tag:tsx]] and instead tag those questions [typescript] + [jsx]. (Or [jsx-syntax] or [react-jsx] or whatever the tag for the language extension will become)

Answer (score 7):

While it might be worth doing *something* here, I think your current proposal is misguided. Here are my issues with it as it stands:

1. [altjs-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altjs-jsx) is a bad name by which to refer to the library that is currently described in the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) excerpt. While the current [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) excerpt does indeed use the term AltJS...

   > JSX is an open source programming language, or an AltJS with classes and static types. The source code is compiled into JavaScript which is highly optimized.

   ... but it seems to be a pretty obscure term. As far as I can tell, [altJS](https://smurfpandey.github.io/altjs/) is a term that was once used to collectively refer to the set of all languages that compile down to JavaScript, and is used in that sense as a [keyword on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:altjs). However, I've personally never heard of it before today, and I note that [a Google search for *altjs*](https://www.google.com/search?q=altjs) shows results related to the Alt.js library first, making this (unrelated) older meaning difficult to uncover. As such, I'd expect anyone with a question about the [JSX language that stopped being maintained in 2015](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/), to which the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag purportedly refers, to be confused by the reference to "altjs" and assume the tag is not really about the language they're asking about.
2. Most existing [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) questions are actually about React. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx yields 3219 results while https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjsx%5D+-%5Breactjs%5D+-%5Breact-native%5D+-react+is%3Aquestion yields only 361; that means that almost 90% of our current [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) questions are really about React JSX. (Probably more, since some are likely about React but missing both the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native) tags.) As such, if we *were* to take the actions you suggest, we would want to first call for a mass retagging by a CM of the 2858 questions that are misusing the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag to refer to React's JSX.
3. Out of the non-React [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) questions, most are *still* not about the library described in the tag excerpt. The next-most-popular thing it's used to refer to, after the XML-in-JavaScript feature used in React, is Adobe Photoshop's ExtendScript. ExtendScript is apparently a JavaScript eXtension (see what I did there?) that is conventionally saved in `.jsx` files.
4. After *that*, the next-most common thing the tag is used for seems to be a library called "JSXGraph", which is older than React and once again totally unrelated to the other uses here.
5. As far as I can tell, *literally nobody ever* has asked a question about the JSX that the tag excerpt refers to. The only reason it's referred to at all is that the Wiki was [edited by the one of the creators of that JSX in mid-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17684482/revisions) to refer specifically to his JSX, right after the first React-related questions started appearing. It might seem like a remarkable claim to make that a project with [thousands of commits and stars](https://github.com/jsx/JSX/) has never had a question asked about it here, but I truly cannot uncover a single example. Even searching for URLs directly related to that JSX just turns up confused people with React-related questions. Here are the searches I tried, without success:

   - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjsx.github.io%2F
   - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22github.com%2Fjsx%2FJSX%2F%22
   - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jsx+--run%22
   - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22jsx+compiler%22+-react+-React.js+-React

   Obviously, it would be pointless to rename the tag to anything the reflects the current excerpt if exactly *zero* percent of questions are using it in the way that the excerpt describes.

All of this finally leads me to a counterproposal with basically nothing in common with your original suggestion. I suggest we, the community, do the following:

- Forget that the JSX described in the tag wiki even exists.
- Repurpose the existing [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag by editing its excerpt to indicate that it refers to the JavaScript syntax extension that permits XML literals to be written directly in JavaScript, as used in ReactJS and Vue.js.
- Manually retag all ExtendScript and JSXGraph questions.

(Note: as of August 21st 2019, the above steps are done.)

That finally leaves the question of what to do with [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx). No synonymisation will succeed at conveying all the information that tag currently conveys, since in theory it tells us that the question is about both [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) and [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx). That's not a problem that either ordinary users or mods can solve. The only proper solution is for a CM to write a script that retags all [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) questions by:

- Adding the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag, and
- Adding the [jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsx) tag, and
- Removing the [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) tag.

Of course, since we don't exactly have limitless CM time on tap to take advantage of, we may never get that. If not, I think that just leaving those old [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) questions alone is probably not the end of the world.

Comment: Ah, I thought you'd post these points as an answer to [the other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315831/proposal-rename-jsx-to-altjs-jsx). I'm totally ok with your proposal about what to do with [[tag:jsx]]. Still, I'd love to see the [[tag:react-jsx]] synonym to be revoked, and - if we follow your proposal - to be synonymised to [jsx].

Comment: @Bergi Oh man, I missed that question's existence entirely, somehow. I'll post a short answer there linking to this one.

Comment: @Bergi I think I disagree with resynonymising [react-jsx] to [jsx]. Presumably anything that somebody chose to tag as [react-jsx] is related to both [reactjs] and [jsx], but out of those two, the [reactjs] tag is clearly the more useful one by far: it has 100k watchers compared to [jsx]'s mere 500, and it seems to me that knowing a question is about React gives me more information than knowing it's about *some* dialect of JSX (maybe React's, or maybe that of Vue or some other framework I've never used).

Comment: @Bergi I'd suggest that if [react-jsx] deserves any fate different from simply remaining a synonym forever, it should be deletion and perhaps blacklisting, after a CM retags all [react-jsx] questions to [reactjs]. It's essentially just a two-tags-in-one tag, and we don't need that, since we can just use both tags individually.

Comment: I would hope that we can have those questions to get both the [reactjs] and [jsx] tags - that's my goal. There older questions that are currently still tagged both [reactjs] and [react-jsx], removing the synonym would help them. For newer questions that were tagged only [reactjs] (due to the input not allowing [react-jsx]), we'd need to manually tag them with both I guess.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, you're right - getting *both* tags on there would be ideal - I didn't think of that. That still sounds like a job for a CM with a retagging script, though, not for the synonym system. My main concern with the resynonymisation you propose is that any questions currently tagged [react-jsx] but *not* [reactjs] will have their tag connection to React severed entirely.

Comment: @Bergi I've edited the proposal at the end of my answer accordingly.

Comment: The [react-jsx] thing that you mention at the end is a CM tool and can be done automatically.

Comment: I've edited the tag as I suggested in this answer. There are >100 of ExtendScript questions to retag, unfortunately - see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjsx%5D+adobe for some. I'll make a start.

Comment: Update: I returned to this today and retagged all the ExtendScript questions that were tagged with `jsx`, and in a few minutes' time I'll have done the same for JSXGraph questions. Mission accomplished.